# Visual Studio Project Load Error: Invalid Cookie : Parameter name: Cookie

Tags: cookies, visual-studio-2013, project

I am experiencing this problem. Has anyone encountered this before or know how to resolve this. I uninstalled my IIS Express and reinstalled it but one project gives me error. Others load fine.

[image]

Answer (score 5):

The following worked for me and didn't require uninstall/reinstall of IIS Express:

1. Open the "applicationhost.config" file located in
   "%USERPROFILE%\Documents\IISExpress\config".
2. Delete all "site" nodes located in the "sites" node (or perhaps just the site associated with your failing project).

Upon successfully opening your project and starting your web application, the site node will be recreated minus any customizations you may have made to it.

Comment: Woot! Just deleting my particular site (not all sites) worked! Thanks for this!

Comment: thanks for this! it work i removed some extra config i added

Answer (score 0):

So to fix this error I had to uninstall IIS EXPRESS and go to documents to delete the IIS Express Folder that has the build Settings and then re-install IIS EXPRESS. Hope this helps if someone else encounters this problem.